# How to pass session id from one page to another in Android Studio?

Tags: android, api, rest, session

Following is the response that i get for a succesfull login. If i logout the token here would change. What I want here is i want to pass token id to another page which has a different url. And each time the token id changes il have to change the token id in the url. How do i do this?? Please Help!!

```
{
    "status": {
    "message": "    ",
    "Code": 200
    },
    "Error_Code": 0,
    "Error_Message ": "",
    "Token": "vqcrk5wp8646th",
    "User Details": {
    "user_reg_id": "123",
    "Name": "ABC",
    }
```

Comment: You should save the token in the SharedPreference

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How do I pass data between activities on Android?](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2091465/how-do-i-pass-data-between-activities-on-android)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Create a **static constant class** to store the token id it can be override when you want to.here how to use assign and use it in any where in application.

```
Class Constant{
public static String token_id=null;
```

}

And set your token after parsing

```
String token_id=json.getString("token");
Constant.token_id=token_id;
```

And Retrieve it when bind to url

```
String existing_token_id=Constant.token_id;
```

OR You can use shared preference to store token id

**Use of SharedPreference**

And set your token after parsing

```
String token_id=json.getString("token");
SharedPreference  pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Activity.this);

SharedPreferences.Editor editor = pref.edit();
            editor.putString("token_id", token_id);
            editor.commit();
```

And Retrieve it when bind to url

```
SharedPreference  pref= PreferenceManager.getDefaultSharedPreferences(Activity.this);

String existing_token_id=pref.getString("token_id",null);
```

Hope this will help you.let me know.

Comment: But how do i store that token in a variable? Im new to this!!

Comment: are you asking to how to parse it??

Comment: yea  does  String token_id=json.getString("Token"); means that ur storing the token value in token_id???

Comment: im really so new to this. im sorry hw do u parse this but??

Comment: if you don't know how to parse JSON then follow this link ..http://www.tutorialspoint.com/android/android_json_parser.htm

Comment: @bythestarz..if you want any help ..ping me any time..have you to success.?

Comment: that did help!! thnx alot! @Andolasoft

Answer (score 0):

use this hope solve your problem

```
SharedPreferences preferences;
String MYPREF="dataRecord";
 SharedPreferences.Editor editor;

preferences=getSharePreferences();

editor=preferences.edit();
//save your session key here
editor.putString("user_reg_id","123");
editor.commit();
```

Comment: But how do i store that token in a variable? Im new to this!!

Comment: what do u use for parsing json data??